# CreateCatalogItem error using ReportingService2010

Tags: ssrs-2012, soap-client

I'm trying to use ReportingService2010 to deploy the datasets and reports to SSRS.  The wsdl definition shows the following method schema for CreateCatalogItem:

```
<s:element name="CreateCatalogItem">
  <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemType" type="s:string" /> 
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string" /> 
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Parent" type="s:string" /> 
         <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Overwrite" type="s:boolean" /> 
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Definition" type="s:base64Binary" /> 
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Properties" type="tns:ArrayOfProperty" /> 
      </s:sequence>
   </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

However, in C# there are more parameters required for CreateCatalogItem.  The parameters are as follows:

[image]
So the extra parameters are TrustedUserHeader and CatalogItem.  I tried passing a null to TrustedUserHeader and created a variable called catalogItem.

The run-time error I get when trying the code below is:

```
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer/CreateCatalogItem.
```

Here is the code:

```
var rs = new ReportingService2010SoapClient(reportBinding.CreateHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(Helper.ReportURI));

rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials.GetNetworkCredential();

string parent = @"http://servername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReportTest&ViewMode=List";
Byte[] definition = null;
Warning[] warnings = null;
Property[] properties = null;
CatalogItem catalogItem;

rs.CreateCatalogItem(null, "Report", @"C:\temp\SelAcctDtl.rdl", parent, false, definition, properties, out catalogItem, out warnings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a service request, creating a web reference solved the problem.

I used the steps from the link below to add the Web Reference to a visual studio project:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43133/Deploying-Reports-in-Reporting-Services-Programmat